# "Root of an equation" vs "Root of a function"

Tags: functions, terminology, roots

I realize that various sources do not differentiate the use of the word *root* for both equations and functions. Should their usage need a revision? I other words, shouldn't we use just *zeros of a function* instead of the *roots of a function*? And, keep roots for just *equations*.

Comment: The terminology I am used to is that polynomials have roots, functions have zeros, and equations have solutions.

Comment: Murat: No, because we speak of roots as applying to functions f(x), polynomial, or otherwise. Speaking of the "roots" of an equation is meaningless. We can also call them zeros of the function. We can describe the values of x which satisfy f(x)=0 as solutions to the equation $f(x)=0$. But those solutions to $ f(x)=0$ are roots or zeros of $f(x),$ not roots of the equation $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score -1):

A root of a function $f$ is a solution $x$ to the equation
$$
f(x) = 0.
$$
For instance, $\pi$ is a root of the equation $x\sin x=0$. (See this [article](https://www.britannica.com/science/root-mathematics) from Encyclopedia Britannica.)

For $g, h$, the root of an equation 
$$
g(x) = h(x) \tag{1} \label{e}
$$
is the $x$ such that the equation (\ref{e}) is true. Observe that we can define
$$
j(x) = g(x) - h(x)
$$
such that the root of $j$ is also the root of equation (\ref{e}).

Comment: having roots is not a property of equation; it is a property of functions.

Comment: EDIT: The edit of my original post makes this comment superfluous.
$$
$$
I disagree. The 'root of an equation' is a [perfectly valid](https://www.britannica.com/science/root-mathematics) way to phrase that the root $x$ satisfies an equation. Some sources recommend refraining from both 'zeros' and 'roots' and instead using simply 'solutions'.

Comment: Indeed, although it is *most* and *all* authoritative sources that recommend refraining from using both 'zeros' and 'roots', when referring to equations, and instead, using simply 'solutions' to equations.